# Python: Identifying and deleting duplicate sequences in list

Tags: python, list, sequences, subsequence

I'm looking for the best way to find duplicate sequences in a list. 
A sequence is defined as at least two neighbouring values.

Example: In the following list, the repeating sequence should be identified and deleted.

```
a = [45874,
    35195, # <-
    28965,
    05867,
    25847, # <-
    94937,
    64894,
    55535,
    62899,
    00391,
    35195, # Duplicate Sequence Start
    28965,
    05867,
    25847, # Duplicate Sequence End
    08483,
    55801,
    33129,
    42616]
```

I can't wrap my head around any solution, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I have sketched down a few non-working bad solutions. I'm pretty much stuck at the beginning - any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Vingtoft what time/space complexity are you looking for

Comment: I think this might be related to strstr algorithms. Have you looked at those?

Comment: And what about overlapping duplicating sequences? does the whole thing get deleted or just one

Comment: @Primusa, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "overlapping duplicate sequences". Only the first appearance of a duplicated sequence is not deleted.

Comment: By example [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]. Should it yield [1, 2, 2, 3] or [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

Comment: Also are these strings? Because you can't input an int beginning with a 0.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thanks for clarifying. It should yield the latter: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]. 
Data is string

Comment: I feel that there is something to be done with the `bisect` module... Have you thought about it? I'm trying to come up with something, but indeed it's tricky...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding a single subsequence of length *m* in a string of length *n* can be done in no less than *O(nm)* with [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm). Finding all duplicate subsequences will most likely be more than that. Although, if all you want is to delete the subsequences and not find them, there is a trick.

### Deleting duplicate subsequences in *O(n)*

We only need to concern ourselves with subsequences of length 2, because any sequence can be expressed as overlapping subsequences of length 2. This observation allows us to keep a count of such pairs and then remove them from right to left.

In particular, this requires traversing the list only a fixed amount of times and is thus *O(n)*.

```
from collections import Counter

def remove_duplicates(lst):
    dropped_indices = set()
    counter = Counter(tuple(lst[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(lst) - 1))

    for i in range(len(lst) - 2, -1, -1):
        sub = tuple(lst[i:i+2])
        if counter[sub] > 1:
            dropped_indices |= {i, i + 1}
            counter[sub] -= 1

    return [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i not in dropped_indices]
```

Here is an example based on the provided input.

```
a = [45874,
     35195, # This
     28965, # Is
     5867,  # A
     25847, # Subsequence
     94937,
     64894,
     55535,
     62899,
     391,
     35195, # Those
     28965, # Should
     5867,  # Be
     25847, # Removed
     8483]

b = remove_duplicates(a)
# Output:
#   [45874,
#    35195,
#    28965,
#    5867,
#    25847,
#    94937,
#    64894,
#    55535,
#    62899,
#    391,
#            <- Here the duplicate was removed
#    8483]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed using the following method, probably not very efficient:

```
sequences=[] #all the sequences, as defined in question
duplicated=[] #all the duplicated sequences
for i in range(2, len(a)): #possible lengths of sequence
    n=0 # index of start of sequence
    for j in a:
        if n+i<=len(a): #if it's not too close to the end
            sequences.append(a[n:n+i]) #add the sequence
        n+=1
tests=sequences[:] #duplicate so that I can remove for checking purposes
for i in sequences:
    tests.remove(i)
    if i in tests: #if it's in there twice
        duplicated.append(i) #add it to the duplicates
for i in duplicated:
    found=False #haven't found it yet
    n=0 #index we're at
    for j in a:
        if a[n:n+len(i)]==i and not found: #if it matches
            del a[n:n+len(i)] #remove it
            found=True #don't remove it again
        n+=1
```

Comment: It deletes the first rather than second appearance, don't know if that's a problem...